# FFMPEG: Cut WMV video not playing on all the media players

Tags: ffmpeg

This is the command line I use to **cut videos** with [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/) (example to cut from minute 1 to minute 6):

```
ffmpeg -i OriginalVideo.wmv -c copy -s 1:00 -t 5:00 CutVideo.wmv
```

It has always worked for me on **any format**, but this is the first time I try it with WMV videos, and things went not as they must.
The resulting file seems to be OK, and the images of each timestamp are there, but **"static"**, this is: the video **does not play** (nor sounds). I can jump to any moment of the video, but the images do not move.
I have tested it with BSPlayer and Media Player Classic.

Why is this happening and how could it be solved?

This is the output for the recoding:

```
ffmpeg -i OriginalVideo.wmv -ss 16:00 -t 27:45 -c copy "CutVideo.wmv"
ffmpeg version N-76041-g0418541 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisy
nth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ico
nv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-li
bdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --ena
ble-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-
amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroeding
er --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enab
le-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --en
able-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
--enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavcodec     57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavformat    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, asf, from 'OriginalVideo.wmv':
  Metadata:
    VBR Peak        : 7000000
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: MP@HL
    WM/WMADRCPeakReference: 32767
    WM/WMADRCAverageReference: 5847
    WMFSDKVersion   : 10.00.00.4005
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    Buffer Average  : 122637
  Duration: 00:46:50.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1675 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 12
8 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1500 kb
/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[asf @ 00000000004f8580] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but contain
er format requires global headers
[asf @ 00000000004f8580] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but contain
er format requires global headers
Output #0, asf, to 'CutVideo.wmv':
  Metadata:
    VBR Peak        : 7000000
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: MP@HL
    WM/WMADRCPeakReference: 32767
    WM/WMADRCAverageReference: 5847
    WMFSDKVersion   : 10.00.00.4005
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    Buffer Average  : 122637
    WM/EncodingSettings: Lavf57.4.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: wmv3 (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16
:9], q=2-31, 1500 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=14102 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   95029kB time=00:07:51.77 bitrate=1650.1kbits/s
frame=35118 fps=35116 q=-1.0 size=  237364kB time=00:19:32.77 bitrate=1658.0kbits/s
frame=49877 fps=35123 q=-1.0 Lsize=  353914kB time=00:27:45.33 bitrate=1740.9kbits/
s
video:317077kB audio:26015kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxi
ng overhead: 3.154253%
```

Further data (thanks you, KC):

- The video generated by FFMPEG plays fine on [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html). So the question is now: how can I generate a video with FFMPEG that plays on any (or most) multimedia players?

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg sometimes encodes things in a way that certain video players can't decode. I would try playing back the file with VLC, VLC has always worked when other video players haven't for me.

Update: I would try converting the video file to a different container, such as mp4, which has worked for you in the past.

Comment: You were right, KC, thanks you. I think the original question must be reworded, then. The question now is more accurate.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a recommendation.